# Anylogic: Location Allocation using agent-based modeling

Tags: anylogic, genetic-algorithm, agent

I'm doing a final research project based on your thesis "Optimal Electric Vehicle Charging Station Location  Allocation using Agent-Based Modeling and Simulation:  A case study of city of Montreal" and facing some problems, can someone help me for that? :(

There are functions that don't have java code to run

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Some more tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help